# How to find the linear application given the function on the basis vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I am given a linear application $f$ from $R^2$ to $R^2$, and I am told it maps $e_1$ to $(1,3)$ and $e_2$ to $(-2,7)$

In this case I know how to find how the linear application acts on a generic vector $(x,y)$:

$$f((x,y)) = f(x e_1 + ye_2) = (x -2y, 3x + 7y)$$

But say I swap $e_1, e_2$ with $(5,3),(-2, 7)$ then how could I do to find how the linear application acts on a generic vector $(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

in this case it must finding the passage matrix from the bases
$B_2=\{(1,3),(-2,7)\}$ to  the $B_1=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$;  as the
passage matrix  from $B_2$ to base $B_1$ is the matrix inverse of
the passage matrix from $B_1$ to $B_2$  and you  know explicitly
the
 matrix  passage $P$ form $B_1$ to $B_2$ that is the matrix   whose colons are vectors $(1,3)$ and $(-2,7)$,  then the wanted  matrix
is  $P^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
{\frac
7{13}} & {\frac 2{13}} \\
{-\frac 3{13}}& {\frac 1{13}}
\end{array}
\right)$ and so $ f (x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
{\frac
7{13}} & {\frac 2{13}} \\
{-\frac 3{13}}& {\frac 1{13}}
\end{array}
\right) (x, y) =({\frac 7{13}x+\frac 2{13}y},-\frac 3{13}x+\frac
{1}{13}y)$.

Comment: When are we using the fact that $(5,3)$ maps to $(1,3)$? it seems like we are not using $(1,3)$ at all.

Comment: sorry the vector  there are no vector $(5,3), it  must be $(1,3)$  I'll fix it now

Comment: the Method is the same, thank you for the correction